# JDBC Change Default Schema

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, schema

I'm trying to connect to a sql server 2005 database via JDBC.

I get the error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The SELECT permission
>   was denied on the object 'MyTable', database 'MyDatabase', schema
>   'dbo'.

The schema I use to connect is "MyUser".  How do I connect using MyUser as opposed to dbo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear things up: You connect to SQL Server using a `user`, not a `schema`. You don't say what version of SQL Server you're connecting to, but it used to be the case that the two were equivalent. As of 2005+, [that is no longer true](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx).

`dbo` is the default schema (think of it as a namespace); what the error message is telling you is the **user** you are connecting with (If I understand correctly, that's *MyUser*) does not have permission to `SELECT` from the *MyTable* table, which is **part** of the *dbo* schema **in** the *MyDatabase* database.

The first thing to do is confirm whether or not the user you're connecting with does or does not have SELECT permissions on that table. The second thing to do is, if it doesn't, either give MyUser that permission or use a different user to perform the SELECT statement.

Answer (score -1):

i found that you have to specify your schema in your **POJOS** definitions.

In my case I got the same trouble using JPA (Entities / Annotations) and I realized that specifing the schema property in the `@Table` annotation works.

for example:

```
@Table(name = "address", **schema="*dbo*"**, catalog = "petcatalog")
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Downvoting because, no matter how many years later, specifying the schema name in code (and the catalog) is a terrible idea. What happens when you change to use a different schema?